# Youtube browser based upload API, which channel it goes to?

Tags: api, video, upload, youtube, youtube-api

With reference to this page...

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading#Browser_based_uploading

On point 6 of the very last potion of the page it says...

The user selects his video and submits the form, sending his video and the upload token directly to YouTube. YouTube verifies the token is valid and adds the video to the user's YouTube channel.

By user's YouTube channel does it mean "uploader's" or "site owner's" channel? Should be site owner right?

Also with the V3, How can i do this aswell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The relevant port of [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading) is

> ACCESS_TOKEN - This value contains the authentication token for your
>   request. The token will either be an OAuth 2.0 access token, an OAuth
>   1.0 access token, a ClientLogin token, an AuthSub single-use token, or an AuthSub session token.

The video will be uploaded into the channel associated with the `ACCESS_TOKEN` value specified in the `Authorization:` header.

As per [best practices](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html), this should be obtained from the end user via [OAuth 2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Authentication) and *not* correspond to the site owner's "master" channel.

Comment: @AvokMatt please note that the browser based upload is not available anymore on V3. The user can upload the video only on its youtube account. Perhaps you should ask him to create a youtube account first and then come back to your website and upload the  video.